# Grails app deploys but has no controllers available

Tags: tomcat, grails, deployment

I finished building all controllers and mappings locally, and they work fine on localhost via run-app, but when i generate the .war to put it on the test server, it deploys and runs, but there's nothing under "available controllers" and my URLs don't work.
I even tried reseting the UrlMapping.groovy to default but still the same error.
Tried in other setups also but nothing seems to work.

looking at the tomcat's log it only shows a message that i thought was unrelated, but may have something to do with it:

```
28/02/2014 14:54:32 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.26/webapps/vistoriaOffline.war
28/02/2014 14:54:33 org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core is already defined
28/02/2014 14:54:33 org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt is already defined
28/02/2014 14:54:33 org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://www.springframework.org/tags is already defined
28/02/2014 14:54:33 org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://www.springframework.org/tags/form is already defined
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.26/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.26/webapps/vistoriaOffline/WEB-INF/lib/grails-plugin-log4j-2.3.6.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory]
```

The only changes to the default BuildConfig.groovy was to add the dependency for the oracle jdbc.

Any ideas what is causing my controllers not to work and how to solve it? thanks.

Comment: Make sure you have `grails.serverURL` set properly in production enviornment in `Config.groovy`.

Comment: @dmahapatro the `grails.serverURL` is set to the correct url, but doesn't work neither `http://localhost:8080/` or `http://test-tom7:8080/` or any other tomcat server i put it in

Comment: If you add the context to `grails.serverURL`, does that fix the problem? So in your case `grails.serverURL = 'http://test-tom7:8080/vistoriaOffline/'`

Comment: @grantmc still have the same error, this project does not have views and all actions return JSON, but tomcat doesn't recognize any of the controllers, it's like the project was an empty new grails app, but it's not.